# Number of sub sequences of a given array that are divisible by n

Tags: algorithm

I have a sequence of numbers say 1,2,4,0 and I have to find number of sequence divisible by 6.

So we will have 0,12,24,120,240 which means answer will be 5,

The problem is that I devised an algorithm which requires `O(2^n)` time complexity so basically it iterates through all the possibilities which is naive.

Is there some way to decrease the complexity.

Edit1: multiple copy of digit is allowed. for example input can be 1,2,1,4,3
Edit2: digits should be in order such as in above example 42 420 etc are not allowed

code: This code however is not able to take 120 into account

```
`#include <stdio.h>
 #include<string.h>
 #define m 1000000007
 int main(void) {
 int t;
 scanf("%d",&t);
 while(t--)
 {
    char arr[100000];
    int r=0,count=0,i,j,k;
    scanf("%s",&arr);
    int a[100000];
    for(i=0;i<strlen(arr);i++)
    {
        a[i]=arr[i]-'0';
    }
    for(i=0;i<strlen(arr);i++)
    {
        for(j=i;j<strlen(arr);j++)
        {
            if(a[i]==0)
            {
                count++;
                goto label;
            }
            r=a[i]%6;
            for(k=j+1;k<strlen(arr);k++)
            {
                r=(r*10 + a[k])%6;
                if(r==0)
                count++;
            }
        }
        label:;
        r=0;
    }
    printf("%d\n",count);
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your current algorithm?

Comment: Very good question! But for me (and seeing the controversal votes) it is slightly off topic and should be moved here: http://cs.stackexchange.com/ ...

Or you should post your code and ask how to get a better performance as suggested earlier.

Comment: You're using terms in an unusual way, which might be confusing.  It seems you're looking for the largest *set* ("sequence" implies order is important) of numbers that can be formed from a given *set* (or possibly multiset, if more than one copy of a digit is allowed) of digits, each of which are divisible by a given number.

Comment: Are multi-digit input numbers allowed?  Are multiple copies of the same number allowed in the input?  Are we allowed to use a single number from the input multiple times?

Comment: I suppose most of the downvotes are due to the problem being poorly explained and to the lack of code of what you tried.

Comment: BTW: If only single copies of single digits are allowed in the input, and we can only use each digit at most once, then there are at most 2^10 = 1024 possibilities, so brute force will be fine.

Comment: multiple copies of single digit is allowed

Comment: I believe that additional clarification is required: do digits need to be in non-descending order? Otherwise, in your original example 42, 102, 204, 210, 402 and 420 are all divisible by 6.

Answer (score 8):

You can use dynamic programming.

As usual, when we decide to solve a problem using dynamic programming, we start by turning some input values into parameters, and maybe adding some other parameters.

The obvious candidate for a parameter is the length of the sequence.
Let our sequence be `a[1]`, `a[2]`, `...`, `a[N]`.
So, we search for the value `f(n)` (for `n` from `0` to `N`) which is the number of subsequences of `a[1]`, `a[2]`, `...`, `a[n]` which, when read as numbers, are divisible by `D=6`.
Computing `f(n)` when we know `f(n-1)` does not look obvious yet, so we dig into details.

On closer look, the problem we now face is that adding a digit to the end of a number can turn a number divisible by `D` into a number not divisible by `D`, and vice versa.
Still, we know exactly how the remainder changes when we add a digit to the end of a number.

If we have a sequence `p[1]`, `p[2]`, `...`, `p[k]` and know `r`, the remainder of the number `p[1] p[2] ... p[k]` modulo `D`, and then add `p[k+1]` to the sequence, the remainder `s` of the new number `p[1] p[2] ... p[k] p[k+1]` modulo `D` is easy to compute: `s = (r * 10 + p[k+1]) mod D`.

To take that into account, we can make the remainder modulo `D` our new parameter.
So, we now search for `f(n,r)` (for `n` from `0` to `N` and `r` from `0` to `D-1`) which is the number of subsequences of `a[1]`, `a[2]`, `...`, `a[n]` which, when read as numbers, have the remainder `r` modulo `D`.

Now, knowing `f(n,0)`, `f(n,1)`, `...`, `f(n,D-1)`, we want to compute `f(n+1,0)`, `f(n+1,1)`, `...`, `f(n+1,D-1)`.
For each possible subsequence of `a[1]`, `a[2]`, `...`, `a[n]`, when we consider element number `n+1`, we either add `a[n+1]` to it, or omit `a[n+1]` and leave the subsequence unchanged.
This is easier to express by forward dynamic programming rather than a formula:

```
let f (n + 1, *) = 0
for r = 0, 1, ..., D - 1:
    add f (n, r) to f (n + 1, r * 10 + a[n + 1])  //   add a[n + 1]
    add f (n, r) to f (n + 1, r)                  //  omit a[n + 1]
```

The resulting `f (n + 1, s)` (which, depending on `s`, is a sum of one or more terms) is the number of subsequences of `a[1]`, `a[2]`, `...`, `a[n]`, `a[n+1]` which yield the remainder `s` modulo `D`.

The whole solution follows:

```
let f (0, *) = 0
let f (0, 0) = 1  //  there is one empty sequence, and its remainder is 0
for n = 0, 1, ..., N - 1:
    let f (n + 1, *) = 0
    for r = 0, 1, ..., D - 1:
        add f (n, r) to f (n + 1, r * 10 + a[n + 1])  //   add a[n + 1]
        add f (n, r) to f (n + 1, r)                  //  omit a[n + 1]
answer = f (N, 0) - 1
```

We subtract one from the answer since an empty subsequence is not considered a number.

The time and memory requirements are `O (N * D)`.
We can lower the memory to `O (D)` when we note that, at each given moment, we only need to store `f (n, *)` and `f (n + 1, *)`, so the storage for `f` can be `2 * D` instead of `(N + 1) * D`.

An illustration with your example sequence:

```
-------------------------------
  a[n]           1   2   4   0
 f(n,r)  n   0   1   2   3   4
    r
-------------------------------
    0        1   1   2   3   6
    1        0   1   1   1   1
    2        0   0   1   2   4
    3        0   0   0   0   0
    4        0   0   0   2   5
    5        0   0   0   0   0
-------------------------------
```

Exercise: how to get rid of numbers with leading zeroes with this solution?
Will we need another parameter?

Comment: Excellent explanation! Can you possibly post the recurrence relation/dynamic program using bottom up approach i.e providing formula for f(n, r) w.r.t the previous result?
One more thing for input "1,2,4,0" you have f(4, 0) as 5 but you subtract -1 in the end so the result is 4 which is not right. Do you think -1 is needed?

Comment: @newbie_old 1. `f(n,r)=` notation is unwieldy, especially when D is not coprime with our base (which is 10). If you really need it, a simple but inefficient notation would be to iterate over all possible remainders: `f (n, r)` is `f (n - 1, r)` plus the sum (for `s = 0 .. D-1` such that `(s * 10 + a[i]) mod D = r`) of `f (n - 1, s)`.

Comment: @newbie_old 2. As for the example, `f (4, 0) = 6` (the number in the upper right corner of the table), and subtracting one is justified as explained (empty sequence).

Comment: I think you meant `f(n,s)=f (n-1, s) + f(n-1, (s*10+a[n]) mod D)` where s = 0 .. D-1 right? I think you mistakenly added `i` and `r` in your comment. Can you explain why this is inefficient as this is also O(n^2) solution as yours isn't it?

Comment: Right, `a[i]` is `a[n]`, sorry! But `s` and `r` are separate values. And the solution becomes `O(N*D^2)` instead of `O(N*D)`, no `N^2` here anyway. The problem with remainders is the following. It is easy to tell what will be the remainder `r` when we have `s` and add a digit. But not so easy to tell what can `s` be so that `(s * 10 + a[n]) mod D = r`. For example, if `D = 6` and `a[n] = 2`, remainders transfer as `0->2`, `1->0`, `2->4`, `3->2`, `4->0`, `5->4`. So, to get `f(n,4)`, we have to sum `f(n-1,4)`, `f(n-1,2)` and `f(n-1,5)`, but to get `f(n,5)`, we just take `f(n-1,5)`.